# R: Create full-length timeseries from an ordered binary set having timestamps

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

Say I have a file which contains a few entries like this:

```
02/10/11 10:26:35 AM UTC, 0
02/10/11 10:26:38 AM UTC, 1
02/10/11 10:26:42 AM UTC, 0
```

Is there any straightforward way, in `R`, to turn this information into a full-length binary timeseries (assuming a one second sampling interval), imputed with zeros and ones?

In this example the series would be: *0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0*

EDIT: Because Dirk and Josh gave unique solutions I wanted to see how they compare in terms of processing time:

```
library(xts)
library(data.table)
library(rbenchmark)

doseq <- function(N,Nby){
  base.t <<- Sys.time()
  t.seq <<- base.t + seq.int(from=0, to=N, by=Nby)
  n.t <<- length(t.seq)
  val.seq <<- (1:n.t - 1) %% 2
}

josh <- function(N,Nby=10){
  doseq(N,Nby)
  dt1 <- data.table(time = t.seq, val=val.seq, key="time")
  dt2 <- data.table(time = with(dt1, seq(min(time), max(time), by=1)), key = "time")
  dtf <- dt1[dt2, rolltolast = TRUE]
  return(dtf)
}

dirk <- function(N,Nby=10){
  doseq(N,Nby)
  xt1 <- xts(val.seq, t.seq)
  secs <- seq(start(xt1), end(xt1), by="1 sec")
  xtf <- zoo::na.locf(merge(xt1, xts(, secs)))
  return(xtf)
}

bm <- benchmark(josh(1e2,10), josh(1e3,10), josh(1e4,10), josh(1e5,10), josh(1e6,10),
  dirk(1e2,10), dirk(1e3,10), dirk(1e4,10), dirk(1e5,10), dirk(1e6,10),
  columns=c("test", "replications","elapsed", "relative"),
  replications=10)

print(bm)
```

giving:

```
              test replications elapsed relative
6    dirk(100, 10)           10   0.024    1.000
7   dirk(1000, 10)           10   0.026    1.083
8  dirk(10000, 10)           10   0.044    1.833
9  dirk(1e+05, 10)           10   0.321   13.375
10 dirk(1e+06, 10)           10   3.342  139.250
1    josh(100, 10)           10   0.034    1.417
2   josh(1000, 10)           10   0.036    1.500
3  josh(10000, 10)           10   0.070    2.917
4  josh(1e+05, 10)           10   0.453   18.875
5  josh(1e+06, 10)           10   5.381  224.208
```

So it seems they aren't too different, but the `xts` method is somewhat faster than the `data.table` method.

Comment: Yes. Could you add the answer to "why" to your question?  I'm guessing what you're trying to achieve as an end result has an even better solution than the one you're looking for.

Comment: Why? Because I'll be sharing data like these with other people, and I'd like to eliminate any ambiguity as to what the numbers represent.

Comment: 0.334s vs 0.538s seems a small difference of mean time. Are you sure that conclusion is robust? It includes the time to create the data in that, too, over and over again in each replication. I see much lower times when timing just the methods. -1 for now, can always be reversed later.

Comment: @Matthew: So does your downvote mean that the post shows no research effort, is unclear, or not useful?  Or you're just confused by the terms "aren't too different" and "somewhat"?

Comment: @Andy Think you're quoting one of the reasons to close there. I didn't vote to close. I downvoted for the reason i wrote in comment above: poor and misleading benchmark in question. I explained, above, why imo the benchmark is poor.

Comment: @Matthew Can you suggest a better method to benchmark the methods?  Perhaps the absolute numbers are reduced by replicating the sequence generation, but this happens in both the 'dirk' and the 'josh' function, so I assume the effect is the same for both sets of benchmarks.

Comment: @Andy Just separate the time to create the data from the time to do the join; ie, time the last line separately as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [xts](http://cran.r-rpoject.org/package=xts) package can help.

First, create an `xts` object:

```
R> pt <- strptime(c("02/10/11 10:26:35 AM", "02/10/11 10:26:38 AM", 
+                    "02/10/11 10:26:42 AM"), "%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
R> vals <- c(0,1,0)
R> x <- xts(vals, pt)
R> x
                    [,1]
2011-10-02 10:26:35    0
2011-10-02 10:26:38    1
2011-10-02 10:26:42    0
Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone (). 
R>
```

We can ignore the warning -- I have a US timezone.

Now, we can create a sequence of seconds from the beginning to the end of that variable:

```
R> secs <- seq(start(x), end(x), by="1 sec")
```

And now for the magic: by merging our original with an 'empty' object of that grid, we expand to the gridL

```
R> x2 <- merge(x, xts(, secs))
R> x2
                     x
2011-10-02 10:26:35  0
2011-10-02 10:26:36 NA
2011-10-02 10:26:37 NA
2011-10-02 10:26:38  1
2011-10-02 10:26:39 NA
2011-10-02 10:26:40 NA
2011-10-02 10:26:41 NA
2011-10-02 10:26:42  0
Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone ().
```

All is left is to call `na.locf()`:

```
R> x2 <- na.locf(merge(x, xts(, secs)))
R> x2
                    x
2011-10-02 10:26:35 0
2011-10-02 10:26:36 0
2011-10-02 10:26:37 0
2011-10-02 10:26:38 1
2011-10-02 10:26:39 1
2011-10-02 10:26:40 1
2011-10-02 10:26:41 1
2011-10-02 10:26:42 0
Warning message:
timezone of object (UTC) is different than current timezone (). 
R>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do that using the **data.table** package:

```
library(data.table)

## Some example data
X <- data.table(time = Sys.time() + c(0,3,7), val=c(0,1,0), key = "time")

## A data.table with one row for each second spanned by X
Y <- data.table(time = with(X, seq(min(time), max(time), by=1)), key = "time")

## Merge them
X[Y, rolltolast = TRUE]
#                   time val
# 1: 2012-09-13 15:58:53   0
# 2: 2012-09-13 15:58:54   0
# 3: 2012-09-13 15:58:55   0
# 4: 2012-09-13 15:58:56   1
# 5: 2012-09-13 15:58:57   1
# 6: 2012-09-13 15:58:58   1
# 7: 2012-09-13 15:58:59   1
# 8: 2012-09-13 15:59:00   0
```

Comment: Same result, different tool.  Thanks.

Comment: @AndyBarbour Nice comment. Noted.